# kernel_task seem to be writing large amounts of data to the disk, but no disk space is used

Tags: mac

According to Activity Monitor, `kernel_task` is writing a large amount of data to the disk. This morning Activity Monitor showed it as having written 46 GB, accounting for 2/3 of all data written. At the same time, the amount of free space did not go down. If Activity Monitor is right, it would have to be overwriting the same files over and over.

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: It could be a combination of things. (Note that these are from my experiences, not research, so it is possible that some of this information is incorrect. That is why I posted it as a comment, not an answer.) 1) Most likely, it is your Time Machine backup task. 2) if you are connected to  system-wide VPN or network storage, that disk transfer information also appears under the guise of kernel_task. 3) it could be rewriting data that already exists (does not take up additional space).